# Get a timestamp from concatenating day and time columns

Tags: postgresql, datetime, casting, concatenation, postgresql-9.1

I am having day and time fields in database. I want to get the time-stamp by concatenating the day and time. How to do this in PostgreSQL?

I have done this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-05-17 10:40:28');
```

And it is working fine.

But when I tried replacing day and time fields I am getting the following error:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP Day || ' ' || Time);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Day"
> LINE 1: ...quest_count > 0 AND (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP Day || ' ' || Time)) > (e...
> ```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (Day || ' ' || Time)::timestamp);
```

Comment: great answer, just want to suggest wrapping it with `to_timestamp` which will put it in timestamp format (currently it is returning me the epoch time)

Answer (score 26):

#### Identifiers?

It's unclear whether you are using upper-case letters in your identifiers, which requires double-quoting.

Also, `Day` is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in SQL and - even though allowed as identifier in Postgres - may require special treatment. I would generally avoid reserved words and basic type names. Double-quoting takes care of it in any case. My standing advice is to use legal, lower-case identifiers that never require double-quoting. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

#### `date` and `time` types

If your column `"Day"` is of type [**`date`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) and your column `"Time"` is of type [**`time`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), there is a very simple solution:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ("Day" + "Time"));
```

You can just add the types `date` and `time` to get a `timestamp [without time zone]`.
Extracting the epoch is unrelated to your question per se. `date` + `time` result in a `timestamp`, that's it.

### String types

If you are talking about string literals or columns of type `text` / `varchar` , use:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2013-07-18' || ' ' || '21:52:12')::timestamp);
```

or:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM cast('2013-07-18' ||' '|| '21:52:12' AS timestamp));
```

Your form does **not** work:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP ('2013-07-18' || ' ' || '21:52:12'));
```

This would work (note the double-quotes):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "timestamp" ('2013-07-18' || ' ' || '21:52:12'));
```

[The manual about type casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

> It is also possible to specify a type cast using a function-like
> syntax:
>
> `typename ( expression )`
>
> However, this only works for types whose names are also valid as
> function names. For example, `double precision` cannot be used this way,
> but the equivalent `float8` can. Also, the names `interval`, `time`, and
> **`timestamp` can only be used in this fashion if they are double-quoted**,
> because of syntactic conflicts. Therefore, the use of the
> function-like cast syntax leads to inconsistencies and should probably
> be avoided.

Bold emphasis mine.
Use one of the first two syntax variants.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me :

```
SELECT CONCAT(Day,' ',Time)::timestamp;
```