# Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table `MyTable`:

```
 id │ value_two │ value_three │ value_four 
────┼───────────┼─────────────┼────────────
  1 │ a         │ A           │ AA
  2 │ a         │ A2          │ AA2
  3 │ b         │ A3          │ AA3
  4 │ a         │ A4          │ AA4
  5 │ b         │ A5          │ AA5
```

I want to query an array of objects `{ value_three, value_four }` grouped by `value_two`. `value_two` should be present on its own in the result. The result should look like this:

```
 value_two │                                                                                    value_four                                                                                 
───────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 a         │ [{"value_three":"A","value_four":"AA"}, {"value_three":"A2","value_four":"AA2"}, {"value_three":"A4","value_four":"AA4"}]
 b         │ [{"value_three":"A3","value_four":"AA3"}, {"value_three":"A5","value_four":"AA5"}]
```

It does not matter whether it uses `json_agg()` or `array_agg()`.

However the best I can do is:

```
with MyCTE as ( select value_two, value_three, value_four from MyTable ) 
select value_two, json_agg(row_to_json(MyCTE)) value_four 
from MyCTE 
group by value_two;
```

Which returns:

```
 value_two │                                                                                    value_four                                                                                 
───────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 a         │ [{"value_two":"a","value_three":"A","value_four":"AA"}, {"value_two":"a","value_three":"A2","value_four":"AA2"}, {"value_two":"a","value_three":"A4","value_four":"AA4"}]
 b         │ [{"value_two":"b","value_three":"A3","value_four":"AA3"}, {"value_two":"b","value_three":"A5","value_four":"AA5"}]
```

With an extra `value_two` key in the objects, which I would like to get rid of. Which SQL (Postgres) query should I use?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

#### [`json_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) in Postgres 9.4 or newer

Or [`jsonb_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) to return `jsonb`.

```
SELECT val2, json_agg(json_build_object('val3', val3
                                      , 'val4', val4)) AS val4
FROM   tbl 
GROUP  BY val2;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE)

> Builds a JSON object out of a variadic argument list. By convention,
> the argument list consists of alternating keys and values.

#### For any version (incl. Postgres 9.3)

[`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) (or [`to_jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE)) with a [**`ROW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) expression does the trick. (Or [`row_to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) with optional line feeds):

```sql
SELECT val2, json_agg(to_json((val3, val4))) AS val4
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY val2;
```

But you lose original column names. A cast to a registered row type avoids that. (The row type of a temporary table serves for ad hoc queries, too.)

```
CREATE TYPE foo AS (val3 text, val4 text);  -- once in the same session
```

```
SELECT val2, json_agg(to_json((val3, val4)::foo)) AS val4
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY val2;
```

Or use a **subselect** instead of the `ROW` expression. More verbose, but without type cast:

```
SELECT val2, json_agg(to_json((SELECT t FROM (SELECT val3, val4) t))) AS val4
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY val2;
```

More explanation in Craig's related answer:

- [Using row_to_json() with nested joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227142/postgresql-9-2-row-to-json-with-nested-joins)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/siXk-Lm1)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/71087/1)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but this returns the object with automatically generated keys: `{"f1":"a","f2":"AA"}`. How to rename `f1` to `value_three`?

Comment: @ehmicky: Right, if you want the column names, too, you need to cast the row to a well-known composite type. I'll add some more.

Comment: A sub-select, or even OP's cte could be a more convenient way for aliasing the row's column names. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227142/postgresql-9-2-row-to-json-with-nested-joins

Comment: @pozs: Good point (and link), I added a code variant accordingly.

Comment: As a style note, I think it's easier for newer folks when we put the updates at the top of the answer and the original notes below it with a note on what version they're applicable for. So long as you maintain the answer it's good forever, and the advice for older PostgreSQL's becomes less useful as time moves on.

Comment: @Evan: I agree. I don't bother to update all my old answers. But since this one needed an update anyway ...

Comment: this worked for my case: `json_agg(to_json(items.*)) as "items"`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Is there any way of doing this where the original type of a timestamp column is retained as a timestamp type rather than being converted to a string? If `value_three` in the example above is a timestamp, it gets converted to string in all of the options you suggested and the application needs to convert it back. While `value_two` in the example will be kept as a timestamp. Any way to have `value_three` handled like `value_two`?

Comment: @user779159; No. JSON itself does not support `timestamp` as datatype. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE. Your options are to store it as string (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860) or as number (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17732668/939860).

Comment: Hello,is there anyway to add DISTINCT in the following query:- json_agg( json_build_object ( 'id', ca.id, 'name',ca.name, 'url',ca.url) ) as authors

Answer (score 0):

**to_json** with **array_agg** with **composite type**

```
begin;
create table  mytable(
id bigint, value_two text, value_three text, value_four  text);
insert into mytable(id,value_two, value_three,value_four)
values
 ( 1, 'a',       'A',           'AA'),
  (2, 'a'    ,     'A2'  ,       'AA2'),
  (3, 'b'  ,       'A3',         'AA3'),
 ( 4, 'a'   ,      'A4',          'AA4'),
  (5, 'b' ,        'A5',          'AA5');
commit;
create type mytable_type as (value_three text, value_four text);
```

---

```
select value_two,
       to_json( array_agg(row(value_three,value_four)::mytable_type))
from mytable
group by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `jsonb_agg` and `to_jsonb`.

```sql
SELECT
    value_two,
    jsonb_agg(to_jsonb (t.*) - '{id,value_two}'::text[]) AS data
FROM
    mytable t
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    1;
```

based on manual reference

> jsonb - text[] → jsonb
>
> Deletes all matching keys or array elements from the left operand.