# Aggregate JSON arrays with column values as keys

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregation, postgresql-9.3

I've got a scenario where I'm trying to aggregate data and insert that aggregated data into another table, all from inside of a function. The data is being inserted into the other table as arrays and JSON. I've been able to aggregate into arrays perfectly fine, but I'm running into some trouble trying to aggregate the data into JSON the way I want.

Basically here is a sample of the data I'm aggregating:

```
 id_1 | id_2 | cat_ids_array
------+------+---------------
  201 | 4232 | {9,10,11,13}
  201 | 4236 | {11}
  201 | 4249 | {12}
  201 | 4251 | {9,10}
  202 | 4245 | {11}
  202 | 4249 | {12}
  202 | 4251 | {9,10}
  202 | 4259 | {9}
  203 | 4232 | {9,10,11,13}
  203 | 4236 | {11}
  203 | 4249 | {12}
  203 | 4251 | {9,10}
  203 | 4377 | {14}
  204 | 4232 | {15,108}
  204 | 4236 | {15}
  205 | 4232 | {17,109}
  205 | 4245 | {17}
  205 | 4377 | {18}
  206 | 4253 | {20}
```

When I use `json_agg()` to aggregate the `id_2` and `cat_ids_array` into a JSON string here is what I get:

```
 id_1 |             json_agg             
------+----------------------------------
  201 | [{"f1":4232,"f2":[9,10,11,13]}, +
      |  {"f1":4236,"f2":[11]},         +
      |  {"f1":4249,"f2":[12]},         +
      |  {"f1":4251,"f2":[9,10]}]
  202 | [{"f1":4245,"f2":[11]},         +
      |  {"f1":4249,"f2":[12]},         +
      |  {"f1":4251,"f2":[9,10]},       +
      |  {"f1":4259,"f2":[9]}]
  203 | [{"f1":4232,"f2":[9,10,11,13]}, +
      |  {"f1":4236,"f2":[11]},         +
      |  {"f1":4249,"f2":[12]},         +
      |  {"f1":4251,"f2":[9,10]}        +
      |  {"f1":4377,"f2":[14]}]
  204 | [{"f1":4232,"f2":[15,108]},     +
      |  {"f1":4236,"f2":[15]}]
  205 | [{"f1":4232,"f2":[17,109]},     +
      |  {"f1":4245,"f2":[17]},         +
      |  {"f1":4377,"f2":[18]}]
  206 | [{"f1":4253,"f2":[20]}]
```

Here is what I'm trying to get:

```
 id_1 | json_agg
------+-------------------------------------------------------------
  201 | [{"4232":[9,10,11,13],"4236":[11],"4249":[12],"4251":[9,10]}]
  202 | [{"4245":[11],"4249":[12],"4251":[9,10],"4259":[9]}]
  203 | [{"4232":[9,10,11,13],"4236":[11],"4249":[12],"4251":[9,10],"4377":[14]}]
  204 | [{"4232":[15,108],"4236":[15]}]
  205 | [{"4232":[17,109],"4245":[17],"4377":[18]}]
  206 | [{"4253":[20]}]
```

I'm thinking that I will have to do some kind of string concatenation, but I'm not entirely sure the best way to go about this. As stated before, I'm doing this from inside of a function, so I've got some flexibility in what I can do since I'm not limited to just SELECT syntax magic.

Also pertinent, I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.4 and cannot upgrade to 9.4 in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pity you cannot upgrade, Postgres 9.4 has `jsonb` and much added functionality for JSON. In particular [`json_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) would be perfect for you:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)

#### Almost, but not quite

While stuck with Postgres 9.3, you can get help from `hstore` to construct an `hstore` value with `id_2` as key and `cat_ids_array` as value:

```
hstore(id_2::text, cat_ids_array::text)
```

Or:

```
hstore(id_2::text, array_to_json(cat_ids_array)::text)
```

Then:

```
json_agg(hstore(id_2::text, array_to_json(cat_ids_array)::text))
```

But the array is not recognized as array. Once cast to `hstore`, it's a text string for Postgres. There is [`hstore_to_json_loose()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE), but it only identifies `boolean` and numerical types.

### Solution

So I ended up with string manipulation like you predicted. there are various ways to construct the json string. Each is more or less fast / elegant:

```
format('{"%s":[%s]}', id_2::text, translate(cat_ids_array::text, '{}',''))::json
format('{"%s":%s}', id_2::text, to_json(cat_ids_array))::json
replace(replace(to_json((id_2, cat_ids_array))::text, 'f1":',''),',"f2', '')::json
```

I picked the second variant, seems to be the most reliable and works for other array types than the simple `int[]` as well, which might need escaping:

```sql
SELECT id_1
     , json_agg(format('{"%s":%s}', id_2::text, to_json(cat_ids_array))::json)
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Result as desired.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/955d9/40) demonstrating all.