# Store SELECT output to 'json' type field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I would like to store some of rows of data in database to as a JSON (in `json` type field) for backup reasons, before transaction is launched.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO public.backup (user_id, data) VALUES (1, (SELECT * FROM ...))
```

Is it possible to do it simple, without parsing select and converting it to JSON in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert whole rows to `json` with [`row_to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

```
INSERT INTO public.backup (user_id, data)
SELECT 1, row_to_json(t)
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  ...;  -- select some rows
```

It's not as simple to preserve column names if the source is a query rather than a plain table. See:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects)

In Postgres 9.4 or later, consider the data type `jsonb` for your data column. Same query, the result is cast to `jsonb` with the assignment automatically.

- [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)

Comment: Actually I used SELECT  array_to_json (array_agg (row_to_json(t)))
FROM   parts.managers t  to put all in one row. Thank you.