# Postgresql 8.4 update query syntax error in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 and creating a plpgsql function. In the body of this function I have a query to update records.

```
...
  UPDATE device_syncfiles SET 
  state_code = 1, updated_at = NOW() at time zone 'UTC'
  WHERE 
  ((state_code = 2 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' - updated_at::timestamp without time zone)) > 3600) OR 
  (state_code = 3 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' - updated_at::timestamp without time zone)) > 3600));
...
```

When I load this function into database, a syntax error turns out

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: UPDATE device_syncfiles SET  $1  = 1,  $2  = NOW() at time z...
                                     ^
QUERY:  UPDATE device_syncfiles SET  $1  = 1,  $2  = NOW() at time zone 'UTC' WHERE (( $1  = 2 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' -  $2 ::timestamp without time zone)) >  $3 ) OR ( $1  = 3 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' -  $2 ::timestamp without time zone)) >  $4 ))
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "syncfile_get" near line 19
```

I cannot find any problem with this query. What's wrong here?

UPDATE: (missing information)

Table: device_syncfiles

```
  id PK integer auto inc
  user_id integer FK
  file_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  state_code integer NOT NULL FK,
  md5 character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  msg character varying(255),
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone
```

Function: syncfile_get()

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION syncfile_get()
  RETURNS TABLE(id integer, user_id integer, file_name character varying, state_code integer, md5 character varying, created_at timestamp without time zone, updated_at timestamp without time zone) AS
$BODY$
      DECLARE
        _device_syncfile_id integer;
        _download_timeout integer;
        _processing_timeout integer;
      BEGIN
        -- GET all timeout info
        SELECT state_timeout INTO _download_timeout FROM device_syncfile_states 
        WHERE state_name = 'downloading';
        SELECT state_timeout INTO _processing_timeout FROM device_syncfile_states 
        WHERE state_name = 'processing';
        -- GET syncfile id
        _device_syncfile_id = NULL;

        -- Reset timed out file to idel state
        UPDATE device_syncfiles SET 
        state_code = 1, updated_at = NOW() at time zone 'UTC'
        WHERE 
        ((state_code = 2 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' - updated_at::timestamp without time zone)) > _download_timeout) OR 
        (state_code = 3 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' - updated_at::timestamp without time zone)) > _processing_timeout));

        -- GET the id of one idel/timed out file => result could be a integer or NULL
        SELECT device_syncfiles.id INTO _device_syncfile_id FROM device_syncfiles 
        WHERE 
        device_syncfiles.state_code = 1 OR 
        (device_syncfiles.state_code = 2 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' - device_syncfiles.updated_at::timestamp without time zone)) > _download_timeout) OR
        (device_syncfiles.state_code = 3 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' - device_syncfiles.updated_at::timestamp without time zone)) > _processing_timeout) 
        LIMIT 1;

        -- WHEN NULL skip state update and return empty set of record
        -- Otherwise return the set of record with the id found in last step
        IF _device_syncfile_id IS NOT NULL THEN
          PERFORM syncfile_update(_device_syncfile_id, 2, NULL);
        END IF;

        RETURN QUERY SELECT 
        device_syncfiles.id,
        device_syncfiles.user_id ,
        device_syncfiles.file_name ,
        device_syncfiles.state_code ,
        device_syncfiles.md5 ,
        device_syncfiles.created_at ,
        device_syncfiles.updated_at 
        FROM device_syncfiles WHERE device_syncfiles.id = _device_syncfile_id;
      END;
      $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Many*** problems.

#### 0.

> I am using Postgresql 8.4

Postgres 8.4 reached EOL in July 2014. [Consider upgrading to a current version.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Urgently.

#### 1.

Your question does not disclose the complete function (at least header and footer) nor any table definition and some sample data to help us help you.

I have to make assumptions, and my educated guess is that you have a function parameter named `state_code`, which conflicts with the identical column name. In ***three*** places. Basics:

- [Postgresql - INSERT RETURNING INTO ambiguous column reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261902/postgresql-insert-returning-into-ambiguous-column-reference/39283973#39283973)
- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

You must be aware the all fields declared in a `RETURNS TABLE` clause are effectively `OUT` parameters as well. (As stated in the first sentence of the first link.) So your Q update confirmed my assumptions.

#### 2.

Your error message reports the ***first*** of those instances here:

```
UPDATE device_syncfiles SET 
  state_code = 1 ...
```

That's a consequence of ***0.***. You are tripping over your long dead and forgotten version of Postgres, where the superficial syntax check at function creation time used to detect a naming conflict between target columns of `UPDATE` statements and function parameters. Which is silly and was later removed: those target columns cannot conflict with function parameters on principal.

Your error reproduced in Postgres 8.4: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=b4b3bad517387ee04f3b4a4d321bb9a2)*

The same does not happen in Postgres 9.4: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=b4b3bad517387ee04f3b4a4d321bb9a2)*

To **fix**, best rename the function parameter to avoid conflicts. Related:

- [Postgres function returning a row as JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142006/postgres-function-returning-a-row-as-json-value/31147662#31147662)

#### 3.

There are two more instances:

```
WHERE 
  ((state_code = 2 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' - updated_at::timestamp without time zone)) > 3600) OR 
   (state_code = 3 AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() at time zone 'UTC' - updated_at::timestamp without time zone)) > 3600));
```

Would need a fix in any version. Postgres cannot tell whether to resolve to the function parameter or the table column. Best table-qualify all columns to avoid any possible conflicts with parameter names a priori. (Except for `UPDATE` target columns, which do not need nor allow table qualification.)

#### 4.

That's still lipstick on a pig. Improve the query like this:

```
UPDATE device_syncfiles d
SET    state_code = 1
     , updated_at = NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
WHERE  d.state_code IN (2, 3)
AND    d.updated_at < (now() - interval '1 hour') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Shorter, faster, can use an index on `updated_at`.

#### 5.

Finally consider using `timestamp with time zone` instead of `timestamp without time zone` to begin with:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot upgrade db because infrastructure change will have too many side effects. And I am pretty sure the variable name does not conflict with table column and state_code is one of the column in device_syncfiles table. I tried to isolated run this update query and its works so just not working when this query is in a function.

Comment: An update: I create a void function just contains this update query says A() then I call: perform A() in the original function. Then all functions works normally. So think this is a postgresql bug in 8.4? Thanks

Comment: @Lester: If you take this seriously, edit your question to provide the missing information.

Comment: @Lester: All fields declared in `RETURNS TABLE` are `OUT` parameters visible in all SQL queries in the function body. It's exactly like I guessed. I clarified some more above.

Comment: awsome! Problem solved! Thank you so much! You are a legend!