# select columns into a json from postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

i have a table employee like this

```
name     value 
'e1'     'rahul'
'e2'     'priya'
'e3'     'abhijit'
```

and i need to extract json from the two columns such that the result is like this

```
{'e1':'rahul','e2':'priya','e3':'abhijit'}
```

I've tried the following query and the results is as follows

```
select row_to_json((name,value)) from employee 

O/P

{'f1':'e1','f2':'rahul'}
{'f2':'e1','f2':'priya'}
{'f3':'e1','f2':'abhijit'}
```

i don't want the f1 and f2 names over there,please advice!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

thanks for the inputs guys but i just found out that i **had to upgrade postgresql from 9.3 to 9.4** to get the function **json_build_object** .it gets the job done with a few changes to the query structure.

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(name,value)) from employee;

[{'e1':'rahul','e2':'priya','e3':'abhijit'}]
```

Comment: what is the point in concatenation with empty string? It seems you could just cast explicitly `name::text`, unless the type of that column is not _text_ already...

Comment: @overdawn You're right. The concatenation is useless .answer updated

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(a) FROM (SELECT name, value FROM employee) a;
```

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question correctly, then, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26486910/939860), in Postgres 9.4+ you might use `json_build_object()`:

```
create temp table employee as (select 'key'::text as name, 'val'::text as value);
select json_build_object(name,value) from employee;
```

Here is the result:

```
json_build_object
-------------------
 {"key" : "val"}
```