# How to group multiple columns into a single array or similar?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I would like my query to return a result structured like this, where `tags` is an array of arrays or similar:

```
id | name | tags
1    a      [[1, "name1", "color1"], [2, "name2", color2"]]
2    b      [[1, "name1", "color1"), (3, "name3", color3"]]
```

I expected this query to work, but it gives me an error:

```
SELECT  i.id, i.name, array_agg(t.tag_ids, t.tag_names, t.tag_colors) as tags 
FROM    ITEMS
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT      trm.target_record_id
            , array_agg(tag_id) as tag_ids
            , array_agg(t.tag_name) as tag_names
            , array_agg(t.tag_color) as tag_colors
  FROM        tags_record_maps trm
  INNER JOIN  tags t on t.id = trm.tag_id
  GROUP BY    trm.target_record_id
) t on t.target_record_id = i.id;
```

Error:

> ```
> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function array_agg(integer[], character varying[], character varying[]) does not exist
> LINE 1: ..., action_c2, action_c3, action_name, action_desc, array_agg(...
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

This query works and produces similar results (but not quite what I want):

```
SELECT  i.id, i.name, t.tag_ids, t.tag_names, t.tag_colors as tags  as tags 
FROM    ITEMS
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT      trm.target_record_id, array_agg(tag_id) as tag_ids, array_agg(t.tag_name) as tag_names, array_agg(t.tag_color) as tag_colors
  FROM        tags_record_maps trm
  INNER JOIN  tags t on t.id = trm.tag_id
  GROUP BY    trm.target_record_id
) t on t.target_record_id = i.id;
```

Result:

```
id | name | tag_ids | tag_names         | tag_colors          
1    a      [1, 2]    ["name1, "name2"]   ["color1", "color2"]
1    a      [1, 3]    ["name1, "name3"]   ["color1", "color3"]
```

Edit:

This query almost produces what I'm looking for, except it names the json keys `f1`, `f2`, `f3`. It would be perfect if I could name them `id`, `name`, `color`:

```
  SELECT        trm.target_record_id, json_agg( (t.id, t.tag_name, t.tag_color) )
  FROM          tags_record_maps trm
  INNER JOIN    tags t on t.site_id = trm.site_id and t.id = trm.tag_id
  GROUP BY      trm.target_record_id
  having count(*) > 1;
```

Result:

```
[{"f1":1,"f2":"name1","f3":"color1"},{"f1":2,"f2":"name2","f3":"color2"}]
```

Comment: Are you using an ancient version of Postgres?

Comment: @GordonLinoff PostgreSQL 11.0 on x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42), 64-bit

Comment: `array_agg()` only takes a single argument (the column to be aggregated). There is no version of that function that takes three arguments. It seems you are looking for some JSON aggregation.

Comment: Are the "results" at the end of your question an example input that should generate a result like the one in the second line of your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(t.id, t.tag_name, t.tag_color)` is short syntax for `ROW(t.id, t.tag_name, t.tag_color)` - and a [ROW constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) does not preserve nested attribute names. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

> By default, the value created by a `ROW` expression is of an **anonymous record type**. If necessary, it can be cast to a named composite type —
> either the row type of a table, or a composite type created with
> `CREATE TYPE AS`.

Bold emphasis mine. To also get proper key names in the result, **cast** to a registered composite type as advised in the quote, use a **nested subselect**, or simply use [**`json_build_object()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) in Postgres 9.4 or newer (effectively avoiding the ROW constructor a priori):

```
SELECT trm.target_record_id
     , json_agg(json_build_object('id', t.id
                                , 'tag_name', t.tag_name
                                , 'tag_color', t.tag_color)) AS tags
FROM   tags_record_maps trm
JOIN   tags             t USING (site_id)
WHERE  t.id = trm.tag_id
GROUP  BY trm.target_record_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

I use original column names, but you can chose your key names freely. In your case:

```
       json_agg(json_build_object('id', t.id
                                , 'name', t.tag_name
                                , 'color', t.tag_color)) AS tags
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

`array_agg()` puts *one* argument into an array.  You could try to concatenate the values together:

```
array_agg(t.tag_ids || ':' || t.tag_names || ':' || t.tag_colors)
```

Or perhaps use a row constructor:

```
array_agg( (t.tag_ids, t.tag_names, t.tag_colors) )
```

Comment: using a row constructor with `json_agg` almost works for me, but i couldn't figure out how to name the columns in my row constructor (how to name the keys in my json object). could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: convert rows to array:
select array_agg(a.*) from item a;

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a `Json_Agg()`?

```
SELECT 
     json_agg(tag_ids, tag_names, tag_colors)
FROM items
```

Etc...

Comment: any suggestion how to use json_agg for my case? with your example, i get this error `ERROR:  function json_agg(integer[], character varying[], character varying[]) does not exist
LINE 1: ..., i.id, i.name, json_agg(t...`

Answer (score 0):

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6a2ab47ddc606ed89a9845e7fbced069)
let's play with composite type.
`create type tags as(tag_id bigint, tag_name text,tag_color text);`

using array_agg:

```
select item_id,name,  array_agg(row(trm.tag_id, tag_name, tag_color)::tags) as tags
from items i join tags_record_maps trm on i.item_id = trm.target_record_id
group by 1,2;
```

to json.

```
select item_id,name, to_json( array_agg(row(trm.tag_id, tag_name, tag_color)::tags)) as tags
from items i join tags_record_maps trm on i.item_id = trm.target_record_id
group by 1,2;
```

access individual/base element of composite type:

```
with a as(
select item_id,name,  array_agg(row(trm.tag_id, tag_name, tag_color)::tags) as tags
from items i join tags_record_maps trm on i.item_id = trm.target_record_id
group by 1,2)
select a.item_id, a.tags[2].tag_id from a;
```