# Select row with all related child rows as array in one query

Tags: sql, node.js, json, postgresql

I'm using Postgres (latest) with node (latest) PG (latest). Some endpoint is receiving json which looks like:

```json
{
   "id": 12345,
   "total": 123.45,
   "items": [
       {
           "name": "blue shirt",
           "url": "someurl"
       },
       {
           "name": "red shirt",
           "url": "someurl"
       }
   ]
}
```

So I'm storing this in two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    total NUMERIC(10, 2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX index_orders_id ON orders(id);

CREATE TABLE items (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    url VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX index_items_id ON items(id);
```

The items table has a FK of order_id to relate the id of the order to its respective items.
Now, the issue is I **almost always** need to fetch the order along with the items.

How do I get an output similar to my input json in one query?
I know it can be done in two queries, but this pattern will be all over the place and needs to be efficient. My last resort would be to store the items as JSONB column directly in the orders table, but then if I need to query on the items or do joins with them it won't be as easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many ways:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_pretty(
          to_jsonb(o.*)  -- taking whole row
      || (SELECT jsonb_build_object('items', jsonb_agg(i))
          FROM  (
             SELECT name, url  -- picking columns
             FROM   items i
             WHERE  i.order_id = o.id
             ) i
         )
       )
FROM   orders o
WHERE  o.id = 12345;
```

This returns **formatted text** similar to the displayed input. (But keys are sorted, so 'total' comes after 'items'.)

If an order has no items, you get `"items": null`.

For a `jsonb` value, strip the `jsonb_pretty()` wrapper.

I chose `jsonb` for its additional functionality - like the [`jsonb || jsonb` → `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) operator and the [`jsonb_pretty()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function.

Related:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)

If you want a `json` value instead, you can cast the `jsonb` directly (without format) or the formatted `text` (with format). Or build a `json` value with rudimentary formatting directly (faster):

```sql
SELECT row_to_json(sub, true)
FROM  (
   SELECT o.*
       , (SELECT json_agg(i)
          FROM  (
             SELECT name, url  -- pick columns to report
             FROM   items i
             WHERE  i.order_id = o.id
             ) i
         ) AS items
   FROM   orders o
   WHERE  o.id = 12345
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8045b3486fa5f2b57355ef56e49cb56f)*

It all depends on what you need *exactly*.

Aside:
Consider type `text` (or `varchar`) instead of the seemingly arbitrary `varchar(128)`. See:

- [Should I add an arbitrary length limit to VARCHAR columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21496/3684)

Comment: This does exactly as described, thank you!
Here's a bit more context for where you mentioned:
- Keys being sorted (total after items key) is completely fine
- Orders will always have at least *one* item, so potentially no need to check for nulls
- The output format doesn't need to be exactly the input, as long as the order row is returned by the select along with: an array of items relating to it or, a json object since the item url is always unique per order.

Comment: - The varchar type was used knowing that text is generally simpler to use and offers the same performance. I did that because I wasn't aware of the CHECK (len) clause and even now, I'm not sure I want to check the length repeatedly where user input ends up written to one of these cols.
Lastly, here's what I did, maybe we could see how it compares in ease of use and performance compared to the sep tables.
I added a JSONB col to orders and changed the input array of items to an object with the url of each item as the top level keys.

Comment: Queries looking to return order rows based on the items within look like this:
`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE jsonb_path_exists(items, '$ ? (@.*.name like_regex "blue" flag "i")') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;`
Now this might be slower or more complicated (I'm guessing) when a query has less to do with the whole order and more with the specific items across multiple orders.