# How to get array of objects in SQL with own key name?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select some categories and sub categories and want to show it all in one array like this:

```
[
 {
   category: 'ELECTRONICS',
   sub_category: 'CONSOLE'
 }
]
```

but I got this:

```
[
    { f1: 'ELECTRONICS', f2: 'CONSOLE' },
    { f1: 'ELECTRONICS', f2: 'CONSOLE' }
  ]
```

here is a code snippet

```
      SELECT 

      s.id,
      s.name,
      s.image,
      s.verified,
      s.s_position,
      s.status,
      s.platform,
      s.coupon_name,
      s.coupon_pct,
      s.coupon_start,
      s.coupon_end,

      json_agg(row(c.category, scg.sub_category)) as categories

....
```

Comment: Have you tried `json_build_object`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Comment: @acurtis166 I just don't believe you really use version 9.5, please use the "current" version to point to the most recent production version: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ...
     , json_agg(json_build_object('category', c.category
                                , 'sub_category', scg.sub_category)) as categories
...
```

See:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects)