# Add LIMIT or ORDER BY inside json_arrayagg()

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, postgresql-16

I have tables `level_one_table`, `level_two_table`, and `level_three_table`.
`level_one_table` to `level_two_table`: one to multiple rows
`level_two_table` to `level_three_table`: one to one row

Goal:  select them all and `level_two_table` rows able to use `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`. Return data structure like below:

```
{
  "level_one_table": {
     "id": ..,
     "... all other field in level_one_table"
     
    "level_two_table": [{
       "id": ..,
       "... all other field in level_two_table",
       
       "level_three_table": {
          "id": ..,
          "... all other field in level_three_table"
       }
    }]
  }
}
```

`level_one_table`:

| "id" | ... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |

`level_two_table`:

| "id" | "fk_level_one_id" | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | ... |

`level_three_table`:

| "id" | "fk_level_two_id" | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | ... |

```sql
SELECT  
  json_build_object(
    'level_one_table', json_build_object(
      'id', t0.id,
      'level_two_table', json_arrayagg(json_build_object(
        'id', t1.id,
        // ... other t1 columns
        // ORDER BY t1.column DESC LIMIT 5
        'level_three_table', json_build_object(
          'id', t2.id
          // ... other t2 columns
        )
      ))
    )
  ) 
FROM level_one_table t0 
LEFT JOIN level_two_table t1 ON t0.id = t1.fk_level_one_id 
LEFT JOIN level_three_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk_level_two_id 
GROUP BY t0.id
// ORDER BY t0.column ...  DESC LIMIT 10
```

Is there a way to add `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY` inside  `json_arrayagg()`?
Or any other solution get the same result?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want 5 elements in `level_two_table` which are determined by the value in `t1.column` descending?

Comment: Yes, order by level_two_table columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the aggregation in a `LATERAL` subquery. Then you can add plain `ORDER BY` & `LIMIT` before you aggregate:

```sql
SELECT json_build_object('id', t1.id /* other t1 cols */
                      , 'level_two_table', level_two_table) AS result
FROM   level_one_table t1 
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(sub) AS level_two_table
   FROM  (
      SELECT t2.id /* other t2 cols */
           , json_build_object('id', t3.id /* other t3 cols */) AS level_three_table
      FROM   level_two_table        t2
      LEFT   JOIN level_three_table t3 ON t3.fk_level_two_id = t2.id
      WHERE  t2.fk_level_one_id = t1.id
      ORDER  BY t2.col DESC
      LIMIT  5
      ) sub
   ) sub;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nxTMilN_)

Notably, I synced table aliases with table names (table names 1-based, but aliases 0-based wasn't helpful).

Here, [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.13.1.1.1) can replace the more sophisticated [`json_arrayagg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.18.1.1.1) (added in Postgres 16) to aggregate the JSON array.

Result:

```json
'{
    "id": 1,
    "level_two_table": [
        {"id": 1, "level_three_table": {"id": 1}},
        {"id": 2, "level_three_table": {"id": 2}}
    ]
}'
'{
    "id": 2,
    "level_two_table": null
}'
```

You get a dummy entry `"level_two_table": null` if there are no related rows. Strip all null values with `json_strip_nulls()`, or use `CASE` or similar to strip electively.

Related:

- [Create JSON object from recursive tree structure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294168/3684)
- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)

For a dynamic number of nested levels:

- [How to turn a set of flat trees into a single tree with multiple leaves?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294044/3684)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will read all ref later, next time try this `LATERAL` feature ^^

Comment: You should try it this time. It's the best tool for the task.

Comment: I tried this https://dbfiddle.uk/1vchar5m it works perfect!! , the approved answer because it count sub table  put that condition outside (end of query) so there is problem . but this `lateral` solve it , thank so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the `ORDER BY` within the [`json_arrayagg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html), but you will need to do the `LIMIT` operation within the query on `level_two_table` by computing a row number for each `fk_level_one_id` and then using a `WHERE` clause at the top-level to only select the first n rows for each group.

```sql
SELECT jsonb_pretty(
          json_build_object(
                'level_one_table',
                 json_build_object(
                     'id', t0.id,
                     'level_two_table',
                      json_arrayagg(
                        json_build_object(
                          'id', t1.id,
                          'column2', t1.column2,
                          'level_three_table',
                          json_build_object(
                            'id', t2.id,
                            'column3', t2.column3
                          )
                        )
                        ORDER BY t1.column2 DESC
                     )
                 )
          )::jsonb
       ) as json_obj
FROM level_one_table t0 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fk_level_one_id ORDER BY column2 DESC) AS rn FROM level_two_table) t1 ON t0.id = t1.fk_level_one_id
LEFT JOIN level_three_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk_level_two_id
WHERE t1.rn IS NULL OR t1.rn <= 2
GROUP BY t0.id
```

I've expanded the demo from the answer to your previous question to demonstrate this in operation [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dCCXpzu3).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/HlarxM_7 `level_one_table` 4 rows and each  related `level_two_table` 2 rows but not work

Comment: @user1775888 in what way is it not working? what should the result be? note in your fiddle you have no rows in `level_two_table` to associate with `id` values of 3 and 4 in `level_one_table`

Comment: I tried to get the result: `level_one_table` 4 rows and each row if `level_two_table` rows  related to `level_one_table` row select  newest 2 row

Comment: but in the demo `ORDER BY t0.id ASC LIMIT 4` cant get 4 rows from `level_one_table`

Comment: @user1775888 like this (adding check for `NULL` `t1.rn`) https://dbfiddle.uk/dejzWLj9 or with matching rows in `t1` https://dbfiddle.uk/sBAbG0ZH

Comment: @user1775888 I take it you found an issue with this answer, can you let me know what it was? If you have a demo showing the problem, I'd appreciate seeing it so I can address it.

Comment: It seems to give exactly the same result as the other answer https://dbfiddle.uk/9ne6Jybv

Comment: Because this way which is counting sub table row then put in outside --> `WHERE t1.rn IS NULL OR t1.rn <= 2`, the way I wanna do is separate `level_one_table` `level_two_table` or level_three_table each condition to select. ex. select `level_one_table` with some condition `AND, WHERE`, if `level_two_table` row is null or count <= 2 it will match too.

Comment: Fair enough, I definitely agree the LATERAL JOIN method makes that more intuitive. Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: thank u for understanding^^ I still learned some from your answer, its very useful