# unknown column ?column? show

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-16

[the way I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77561090/1775888) like this answer, its all fine get the data I want, but in my project real use, sub table `level_two_table` it shows one unknonw column
`?column?`  so strange, also not just key there is value exist too.

Anyone what is that? How to solve it?  I searched google but cant find related answer,
tried demo in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1vchar5m) didnt show.

This is on my local computer Mac, and install PostreSQL 16 through Homebrew,
its not just showing with my code my project, I also did test with pgAdmin it shows too.

```
...
level_two_table: [
    {
        '?column?': 'email',
        id: 3,
        level_three_table: { ... }
    }
]
```

Comment: I have not looked at the SQL, but `'?column?'` occurs when you create an expression in the SELECT list that you don't give an alias to e.g. `select 1 * 2;  ?column? 
----------`
        2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the column name ("alias") that PostgreSQL chooses when you don't specify anything in the query and it cannot make a good guess.

The following statement and its result demonstrates that:

```
SELECT /* the column name is used for this result column */
       datname,
       /* the function name is used for this column */
       upper(datname),
       /* PostgreSQL has no guud guess and uses "?column?" */
       encoding + 1
FROM pg_database
WHERE datname = current_database();

 datname │ upper │ ?column? 
═════════╪═══════╪══════════
 test    │ TEST  │        7
(1 row)
```

If you don't like that, specify your own aliases:

```
SELECT datname AS database,
       upper(datname) AS db_upper_case,
       encoding + 1 AS pointless_number
FROM pg_database
WHERE datname = current_database();

 database │ db_upper_case │ pointless_number 
══════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════════
 test     │ TEST          │                7
(1 row)
```