# How to suppress key for elements of aggregated JSON array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

Working with `jsonb` and Postgres I'm running into the following problem:

My output looks like this: `[ {columnName: {}}, { columnName: {} } ]`
But I would like it to look like this: `[ {}, {} ]`

I want to put all of the objects in a `jsonb` array, but without the column names being added.

Here is the basic query, which can be seen in this fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b701b8/2

I've noticed that when using `array_agg()`, the column names are not added, but with JSON they do get added.  How to remove the column names so that I can get the desired output using JSON?

```
select json_agg(v)
from (
  select json_build_object('pos',pos, 'type',type, 'color',color)
  from (select * from images)a
  union all 
  select json_build_object('pos',pos, 'type',type, 'value',value)
  from (select * from letters)b
)v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate the **column** instead of the whole row:

```
SELECT json_agg(v.image) AS images
FROM  (
   SELECT json_build_object('pos',pos, 'type',type, 'color',color) AS image  -- !
   FROM   images i -- simpler

   UNION ALL
   SELECT json_build_object('pos',pos, 'type',type, 'value',value)
   FROM   letters l  -- simpler
   ) v;
```

Notably, your query produces `json`, not `jsonb`.
Simpler while nesting **whole rows**:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(v.image) AS images
FROM  (   
   SELECT to_json(i) AS image
   FROM   images i

   UNION ALL
   SELECT to_json(l)
   FROM   letters l
   ) v;
```

Similar for **`jsonb`** (where whitepace is a non-issue)

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(v.image) AS images
FROM  (   
   SELECT to_jsonb(i) AS image
   FROM   images i

   UNION ALL
   SELECT to_jsonb(l)
   FROM   letters l
   ) v;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SEcHTOAd)

See:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

If column types really match between these two tables, you can shorten the query by labelling the rows and building your `jsonb` right where you aggregate: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lfiakgNJ)

```sql
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('pos',pos,'type',type,label,color_or_value))
from (select pos, type,'color' as "label",color as "color_or_value" from images
      union all 
      select pos, type,'value' as "label",value from letters )v;
```

| jsonb_agg |
| --- |
| [{"pos": 0, "type": "image", "color": "red"}, {"pos": 1, "type": "image", "color": "blue"}, {"pos": 2, "type": "text", "value": "book"}] |