# SQL: Add UTC timestamp column to table from date and time

Tags: sql, postgresql, utc

I have a table in Postgres that has a date column and time column.  I would like to add a new column that has utc (or timestamp) values based on on the date and time columns.

I tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (utc) SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (date || ' ' || time )::timestamp);
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR: column "date" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Hint: There is a column named "date" in table "mytable", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

And there definitely are the columns date and time.

Does anyone know how to add values to UTC column based on date and time columns?
For example:  09/21/2012 12:56:00 should become something like 411730.830555

I'm trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725418/get-a-timestamp-from-concatenating-day-and-time-columns) (I think).

Comment: `insert` is there to insert new **rows**. New columns are added with `alter table add column`. But in general it's a bad idea to store data that can easily (and cheaply) be derived from the one that is already there. Create a view that contains that column, there is no need to duplicate information. And why are you storing date and time in two columns? Why don't you use a single `timestamp` column?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I can't manually create a UTC date-time value for every row.  But I happen to have a table that was already created that has date and time values.  To use a single UTC column, I need to be able to create those values based on existing values.

Comment: Also, depending on the situation, it can be helpful to have multiple columns that explain different parts of data or are readable in different ways.  In this example, seeing a UTC date like 411730.830555 may be meaningless to a human, but is required for functionality, and so it may be nice to have the date and time columns as well.

Comment: No, it is **not** "helpful" to store data redundantly. If you need to display a timestamp column in different formats, create a view that does that. Do not store the same information multiple times.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you are trying to do. `alter` the table to have a new `timestamp` column? `extract(epoch...)` does **not** return a timestamp value, it returns an integer value. A `timestamp` is something completely different: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I want to take a date value and a time value and create a utc value like 411730.83055.  Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725418/get-a-timestamp-from-concatenating-day-and-time-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting from the other answer was actually different than what I wanted, upon further investigating.

I mentioned the formatting desired was `ddddd.tttttt` where `d` is a numerical version of a date (specifically, the number of days since 1900-01-00), and `t` is a fraction of 24 hours.  This is the format Excel uses to store date-time values, called "serial date-time." For more information see [Dates and Times in Excel.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm)

I thought this was similar to postgresql's timestamp format, but it turned out to not work for my purposes.

**This is what worked:**

`UPDATE mytable
SET utc = DATE_PART('day', '2012-09-21'::timestamp - '1899-12-30'::timestamp) + (EXTRACT( HOURS FROM time::time)/24) + (EXTRACT( MINUTES FROM time::time)/1440) + (EXTRACT( SECONDS FROM time::time)/86400);`

Just wanted to update the answers for accuracy and in case anyone else stumbles into this problem.  It appears there's little information on how to do this on the internet.  I appreciate the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name; that did help me in some ways.

Comment: Again: do **not** do that. Store a regular `timestamp` and format that to whatever you want when you _display_ it. Storing redundant information is a bad idea

Answer (score 4):

#### What you want to do

To *add* a new *column* you need an `alter table` statement:

```
alter table mytable add column utc float;
```

Then you need to update that column with the new data:

```
update mytable
  set utc = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (date || ' ' || time )::timestamp);
```

You now need a trigger that keeps the date/time and utc columns in sync.

#### What you should do

The above is not a good idea. The rule of thumb in a relational database:

**Never store information that can be derived from the data that is already in the database.**

So the clean solution is to not store date and time in two different columns and not add another column that contains exactly the same information in a different representation.

You should have a single column with the type `timestamp`, then create a view that returns that `timestamp` with the different formats you want:

```
-- add the new timestamp column
alter table mytable add column ts_column timestamp;

-- copy the data 
update mytable
  set ts_column = (date || ' ' || time )::timestamp;

-- get rid of the old columns
alter table mytable 
     drop column date, 
     drop column time;

-- now create a view that display the information in different ways              
create view formatted_mytable
as
select id, 
       ts_column, 
       to_char(ts_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as date_only, 
       to_char(ts_column, 'hh24:mi:ss') as time_only, 
       extract(epoch from ts_column) as epoch
from my_table;
```

That way you don't need to duplicate the information stored in the table just because you need a different display format.

Comment: What worked was changing: `INSERT INTO mytable (utc) SELECT` to `set utc = `.