# How to make an EXCLUDE constraint with date + time values? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

As the title suggests, what I'm trying is to create an `EXCLUDE` constraint by concatenating `date + time` values.

Here is a DB table called `bookings`:

```
column name | data type
----------------------
date        | date
start_time  | time
end_time    | time
```

`start_time` and `end_time` aren't `timestamp`. They are `time`.

Here's a SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE bookings
ADD CONSTRAINT overlapping_times
EXCLUDE USING GIST (
  tsrange(date + start_time, date + end_time) WITH &&
)
```

The purpose for the constraint is to prevent `bookings` table from having multiple rows with overlapping time ranges on the same date.

`tsrange` is available for `timestamps`, not `time`. So, by following [Postgres' doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), I concatenate date and start_time (and end_time). The doc shows the following example:

```
date + time → timestamp
Add a time-of-day to a date
date '2001-09-28' + time '03:00' → 2001-09-28 03:00:00
```

However, the SQL above results in:

> error: data type integer has no default operator class for access
> method "gist"

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Thank you @Tim Otomagis. It seems that I was using an old version of Postgres which can't create `timestamp` by `date + time`

So, by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17725940/3655192), I tried the following:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE bookings
ADD CONSTRAINT overlapping_times
EXCLUDE USING GIST (
    tsrange(
        CONCAT(date::date || ' ' || start_time::time)::timestamp,
        CONCAT(date::date || ' ' || end_time::time)::timestamp
    ) WITH &&
);
```

However, this results in:

> functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

**EDIT 2**

I ended up upgrading Postgres from v12 to v14 to make the original approach work. Thanks again @Tim Otomagis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry I was unable to recreate the problem. when I try SQL code above it works as expected. I'm using PostgreSQL 14.

[sample result with DBeaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGizB.png)

Comment: Hmm ok... The version of Postgres on my machie is `PostgreSQL 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit`